# How to convert CSV to JSON?

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file with the header as Key and the data as the Value. My goal is to convert the CSV file into Json to upload into a database and output the data I uploaded. I have successfully converted the CSV into Json,but I am having trouble with my output.

What I currently have

```
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd
csvfile = open ('so-emissions-by-world-region-in-million-tonnes.csv','r')
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
result = []
for row in reader:
    result.append(row)
result = json.dumps(result)
result = json.loads(result)
keys = ('Entity' ,'Year','SO2 emissions- Clio Infra')
print(result)
```

CSV Data:

```
[{'502 emissions- Clio Infra': '0', 'Entity': 'Africa', 'Year': '1860 '},
 {'502 emissions- Clio Infra': '0', 'Entity': 'Africa', 'Year': '1870'},
 {'502 emissions- Clio Infra': '0.059', 'Entity': 'Africa', 'Year': '1880'},
 {'502 emissions- Clio Infra': '0.065', 'Entity': 'Africa', 'Year': '1890'},
 {'502 emissions- Clio Infra': '0.071', 'Entity': 'Africa', 'Year': ' 1900'},
 {'502 emissions- Clio Infra': '0.146', 'Entity': 'Africa', 'Year': '1910'},
 {'502 emissions- Clio Infra': '0.372', 'Entity': 'Africa', 'Year': '1920'},
 {'502 emissions- Clio Infra': '0.41', 'Entity': 'Africa', 'Year': ' 1930'},
 {'502 emissions- Clio Infra': '0.56 ', 'Entity': 'Africa', 'Year ': '1940'}]
```

[This is the output of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ8tO.png)

Correct output:

```
'First Key'
Value 1
Value 2
Value 3
...
'Second Key'
Value 1
Value 2
Value 3
...
'Third Key'
Value 1
Value 2
Value 3
...
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `csv.DictReader` to read your CSV and then serialise its output with `json.dumps`.

```
import csv
import json

data = []
with open('file.csv') as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f):
        data.append(row)

json_data = json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: I have something similar to what you have suggested, but I can't get my output to print like the way I need it. So I know that I cannot do json_data["Key"] to print >> 'Value 1'..... because It is not tuple

Comment: @AlexisChen `json_data` is a string... if you want to print k-v pairs, you'll want to access `data[i]`.

Comment: Thanks! I figure it out :) I wrote a for loop to access the k-v pairs

Answer (score 1):

You are currently printing the result which is the dictionary itself, if you want to get the output in a nice format as shown in the question, you need to go through the dictionary to print out each key and its values

```
for key in keys:  #looking through each key
    print (key)
    for i in results:  #going through the results and printing the value of the index with the current key
        print (results[i][key])
```

This should give the expected output in the console as mentioned in question

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `.to_dict` if you load your data in a dataframe.

```
df = pd.read_csv('so-emissions-by-world-region-in-million-tonnes.csv')
df.T.to_dict().values()
```

`.to_dict()` turns your dataframe in a map by columns (for each column you have index->value). By transposing and using `.to_dict`, this is a map by rows (for each index you have a map column->value). You don't need the keys, so just take `.values()`

Be careful, this is a `dict_values` object if you are using python 3.5, so you may want to use `list()` before converting to json.

By the way, you can also use `dict(zip(columns, values))` to get a map column->value for each row, which is faster. In that case you don't need pandas at all.

edit: if the csv has no header, you need to pass it in the `pd.read_csv()` with keyword `names=`