# Is there an app for mac to create JSON from table and adding data types?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a big database with thousands of entries .. I have it in excel tables .. now I want to convert it to JSON for FIREBASE.

The problem is that online tools don't offer data types and just convert all into strings .. and there is a website that offers data types but need to be edited manually which is impossible with thousands of entries.

Comment: You might have to write your own custom logic to transform your csv or excel to JSON. Have look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46091769/how-to-convert-csv-to-json

Comment: Thanks a lot .. but I was looking for an app to do that so that non programmers can use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have not heard of any app but the easiest i know of is Mockaroo https://mockaroo.com